# Will I get a ResourceNotFoundException when I try to retrieve a String from Context in an Api?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I added a context on my API class that retrieves data from Firebase. If the retrieval fails I return a String that I get from my resources. I just wondered let's say the fragment or activity was suddenly destroyed. Won't I get a ResourcesNotFoundException?

E.g.

I retrieved data > Locked my Screen > Retrieval Fails > (Possible ResourceNotFoundException)?

If this is true then would it be okay to make a StringFactory in a AndroidViewModel, and use the applicationContext to retrieve the String

or

Just fully return a constant var that the Observer will receive, then allow the Observer to access the Context to get the String I need from Resources?

Here are my classes below.

```
interface BaseApi<T> {

    val process: MutableLiveData<Response<T>>

}
```

---

```
class AccountApi(val context: Context, val store: FirebaseFirestore) : BaseApi<AccountDocument> {

    override val process: MutableLiveData<Response<AccountDocument>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getAccountDocument(email: String): LiveData<Response<AccountDocument>> {

        val collection = store.collection("accounts")

        collection.document(email)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { task ->
                    process.value = Response<AccountDocument>(true).data(task.toObject(AccountDocument::class.java))
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    process.value = Response<AccountDocument>(false).message(context.getString(R.string.account_does_not_exist))
                }

        return process
    }
}
```

---

```
data class Response<T>(
        val isSuccessful: Boolean = false
) {
    private var _message: String = ""
    private var _data: T? = null

    fun message(message: String): Response<T> {
        _message = message
        return this
    }

    fun getMessage() = _message

    fun data(data: T?): Response<T> {
        _data = data
        return this
    }

    fun getData() = _data

}
```

Comment: You will not get `ResourceNotFoundException` You can not use `Context` which is destroyed. You can have an `Application` class to provide `Context` globally in this case .

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is a common issue when you add the string to a different locale than the default `strings.xml` file and forget to add it to the default `strings.xml` file.
So when you are in the default locale, the app will not be able to see the value because it's not inside the default `strings.xml`